# Multiple element types in ng-transclude-slot?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm doing multi-slot transclusion. My directive template (important bits):

```
<div>
  <div ng-transclude-slot='title'></div>
  <div ng-transclude-slot='body'></div>
</div>
```

Right now my `transclude` property in my directive definition looks like this:

```
transclude: {
  title: '?h1',
  body: '?div'
}
```

What if I want title to be able to take more than just `<h1>` elements though? Something like:

```
transclude: {
  title: '?h1?h2?h3',
  body: '?div'
}
```

Comment: you will have to wrap h1 h2 h3 in a div and transclude the div

Comment: @gyc that might work because `div` and `h*` are all block level elements but it seems like it would break down if the slot can take entirely different types of elements right?